# Ignore Maven test dependencies in compile phase

Tags: maven

I have a multi-module maven project with a shared test module. I import the tests in other modules with

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-test-module</artifactId>
    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I run `mvn clean compile` for the first time to just build `src/main/java` I get a build error `Could not find artifact org.example:some-test-module:jar:tests:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`. When I run `mvn clean test-compile` everything works as expected.

How can I compile `src/main/java` with `mvn compile` without the up to this phase missing test-jar?

Comment: The simplest solution to such issue is to make a separate module which contains the tests classes but put them into `src/main/java` and others module define it as a usual dependency with the scope `test`...

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can't.

On the other hand, why run `mvn clean compile`? For what purpose? Why not just run `mvn clean verify`?

These `test-jar`s are often a bad idea and I haven't understood yet what purpose they serve.

Comment: I need this in a CI/CD setup. There is a build step executing `mvn clean compile` then there is a test step executing `mvn test` and so on.

Comment: Why separated `mvn clean compile` and `mvn test` because `mvn. test` will repeat a lot of steps done in `mvn clean compile` ... sounds like a misunderstanding of the life cycle

Comment: @user15110545 In a CI/CD setup, you just call `mvn clean deploy`, you don't do `compile` or `test`.

Comment: If I execute first `mvn clean compile` and then `mvn test` the second command uses the build output from the first command.

Comment: @user15110545 Yes, but why? Why not do it the easy way and just do `mvn clean deploy`?